# Проблемы с рефакторингом AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-studio

При попытке поменять тип переменной AndroidStudio  выдает такое сообщение

```
Cannot perform refactoring. Selected class is not located inside project
```

Comment: проект не импортирован в студию значит

Comment: @АндроидАндроид а что значит "не импортирован"  как его можно импортировать?

Comment: file>new>import project

Comment: @АндроидАндроид сделал, перезагрузил - не помогло!